# Unable to create ELB with 2 kubernetes clusters in the same AWS VPC and subnets using kops solution

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

We are trying to test if we can have 2 or more k8s cluster in the same AWS VPC and Subnets (public and privates) using kops solution https://github.com/kubernetes/kops

We build the cluster with no issues, but when we try to expose a service through the ELB, it fails.

If we modify the subnet tag `KubernetesCluster` to the new cluster name, the ELB is published.

Is it possible to have multiple k8s cluster built with kops in the same subnets?

The `KubernetesCluster` tag supports multiple clusters?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the kops [documentation on shared subnets](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/run_in_existing_vpc.md#shared-subnets):

> If you run in AWS private topology with shared subnets, and you would
>   like Kubernetes to provision resources in these shared subnets, you
>   must create tags on them with Key=value
>   KubernetesCluster=. This is important, for example, if
>   your utility subnets are shared, you will not be able to launch any
>   services that create Elastic Load Balancers (ELBs).

Which means that yes, you will need to set the KubernetesCluster tag if you want resources that need ELBs.